# load several Lua modules with single require

Tags: lua

I am stuck on a Simple problem of loading several modules without explicitly requiring all of them.
My modules are tables of register address and default values

Here is the directory structure and each module contains a table(same name as module itself) i-g A01.lua has A01 = {} and so on

```
 main.lua
 map/registers/A01.lua
 map/registers/B20.lua
 map/registers/C31.lua  -- [100+]
 map/registers/XYZ0119.lua
```

I can load individual modules by using

```
local regMap = require('map.registers.A01')
regMap = require('map.registers.B20') -- and so on
```

But this is not optimal, Since I have 100s of them. and they will be over written 

Is there any way to import all of them at once?
or Is there any way to load a certain table on "need" basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution for this:

```
   local regMap = {} -- Define Master table

   -- Load a module whenever missing filed appears
   setmetatable(regMap,{__index =  function (t, k)
        t[k] = require ('map.registers.' .. k)
        return t[k]
      end})

   -- Call any module
    regMap['A01']
    regMap['B20']
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a "remake" of Alban Linard's answer but without using external libraries.

```
-- Assume that all your files are inside "map/registers" folder 
-- (no recursive subdirectories search is performed)

for filename in io.popen('ls -pUqAL "map/registers"'):lines() do      --Linux
--for filename in io.popen('dir /b/a-d "map\\registers"'):lines() do  --Windows
   filename = filename:match"^(.*)%.lua$"
   if filename then
      require("map.registers."..filename)
   end
end
```

Comment: Why not simply `ls map/registers/*.lua` ?

Comment: @lhf - After `mkdir map/registers/Misc_Modules.lua;touch map/registers/Misc_Modules.lua/some_module.lua` require will try to load `some_module` and will fail to do that

Comment: My idea is to load modules whenever i need one of the Register name for any of above files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`luafilesystem`](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/) module to iterate over the files in the `map/registers/` directory, and they load the modules:

```
-- Luafilesystem allows to iterate over a directory.
local Lfs = require "lfs"

-- for each filename in the directory
for filename in Lfs.dir "./map/registers/" do
  -- if it is a file
  if Lfs.attributes ("./map/registers/" .. filename, "mode") == "file" then
    -- transform the filename into a module name
    local name = "map/registers/" .. filename
    name = name:sub (1, #name-4)
    name = name:gsub ("/", ".")
    -- and require it
    require (name)
  end
end
```

Note that `name = name:sub (1, #name-4)` removes the extension, but we do not have checked that it is a `.lua` file.

Comment: this approach is pretty smart, but i prefer to use metatables.

Comment: Yes, using metatables is better for the last version of your question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you had in mind, but I would do:

```
rm -f map/registers/all.lua
( for f in map/registers/*.lua; do f="$( basename "$f" .lua )"; echo "require('map.registers.$f')"; done ) > map/registers/all.lua
```

And then use

```
require("map.registers.all")
```

in your code.